# Can I reuse a declared pointer if it's deleted?

Tags: c++, pointers

In a linked list, I have the following code

```
Node *tmp = head;
Node *del = head->next;
tmp->next = del->next;
delete del;
del = tmp->next;
```

In my code, I deleted the pointer `del` first, later I point it to `tmp->next`. Will this work?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: @OliCharlesworth ......... but call undefined behavior!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Why UB here?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Ah, I see! It's just reassigned, not dereferenced. So no, of course no UB!

Comment: Think of it like this: You store the address of head, you delete the value stored at the address (no longer valid pointer), then you change the stored address (now a valid pointer); so long as the stored address is valid the pointer is safe to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually delete the pointer variable itself, you just mark the memory area that it *points to* as free to use for future allocations (after calling the destructor but that's a different topic). The pointer variable just carries an address. Even after deletion the pointer variable is fine, but it points to an area in memory that has been freed, so its contents are undefined.

When the pointer variable is then reassigned to point to another memory address, it will have nothing to do with the old, "deleted" part of memory at all.